# Change the uppercase to lowercase using Perl script

Tags: uppercase, lowercase

I have the file which has uppercase words, and I need to change them to lower case whole through the file. I have used the below code to change them, but only the first character is getting changed. I would like to change the entire content which is available inside the tag SC (globally).

```
$xtx1 =~ s/<sc>(.*?)<\/sc>/\l$1/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the next one

```
filePath = 'sample.txt';
# Go line by line and change to lowercase
tmpPath = mkstemp()
with open(tmpPath, 'w') as newFile:
    with open(filePath) as oldFile:
        for line in oldFile:
            # Apply pattern
            tmp = re.sub('^(.*?)\<\/sc\>.*', lambda m: m.group(0).lower(), line)
            newFile.write(tmp)

close(oldFile)
close(newFile)

# Remove original file
remove(filePath)

# Move new file
move(tmpPath, filePath)
```

Comment: This will change the entire contents in that file, but i specifically need to change certain contents which is available in <SC> tag.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply, actually i have requested Perl script for this conversion and finally i have found the answer, $xtx1 =~ s/(.*?)</sc>/\L$1/g;

Comment: This is python, not perl.